# Convert this series of foreach loops to LINQ expression

Tags: linq

I have a generic method which adds all the html controls I have on a page into a generic list using a series of foreach loops which works. Is it possible to convert this into a LINQ expression?

```
private List<T> GetControls<T>() where T : HtmlControl
         {
            List<T> c = new List<T>();

            foreach (HtmlControl c1 in Controls)
            {
                foreach (HtmlControl c2 in c1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c2.GetType() == typeof(HtmlForm))
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3.GetType() == typeof(ContentPlaceHolder))
                            {
                                foreach (HtmlControl c4 in c3.Controls)
                                {
                                    if (c4.GetType() == typeof(T))
                                    {
                                        c.Add((T)c4);
                                    }
                                    if (c4.GetType() == typeof(PlaceHolder))
                                    {
                                        foreach (HtmlControl c5 in c4.Controls)
                                        {
                                            if (c5.GetType() == typeof(T))
                                            {
                                                c.Add((T)c5);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return c;
        }
```

Comment: The [Visitor](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) design pattern will help to disentangle code like this.

Comment: Cheers Jon, shall look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
List<T> c = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .SelectMany(c1 => c1.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    .OfType<HtmlForm>()
    .SelectMany(c2 => c2.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    .OfType<ContentPlaceHolder>()
    .SelectMany(c3 => c3.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    .SelectMany(c4 =>
        {
            if (c4 is T)
                return new[] { (T)c4 };
            if (c4 is PlaceHolder)
                return c4.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<T>();
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        })
    .ToList();
```

However note I've used `is` instead of a type comparison here. This is deliberate, because this is what the `OfType` LINQ method also uses internally.

If you're sure you want exact types rather than objects that pass an `is` comparison, you'll have to implement your own `OfType` (or just use `.Where(x => x.GetType == typeof(whatever))` instead.)

(Also note that I've used `Control` instead of `HtmlControl`, in case some of your `HtmlControl`s contain regular `Control`s.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
 private List<T> GetControls<T>() where T : HtmlControl
    {
        List<T> c = new List<T>();

        foreach (HtmlControl c4 in from HtmlControl c1 in Controls
                                   from HtmlControl c2 in c1.Controls
                                   where c2.GetType() == typeof (HtmlForm)
                                   from Control c3 in c2.Controls
                                   where c3.GetType() == typeof (ContentPlaceHolder)
                                   from HtmlControl c4 in c3.Controls
                                   select c4)
        {
            if (c4.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                c.Add((T)c4);
            }
            if (c4.GetType() == typeof(PlaceHolder))
            {
                c.AddRange(from HtmlControl c5 in c4.Controls where c5.GetType() == typeof (T) select (T) c5);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Although I'm not sure it's any more elegant ...

Comment: Thanks for your contriibution RedEyedMonster, although this seems to throws an InvalidCastException.